# SQL Database Mail- status sent but never receiving email on Microsoft email

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, hotmail

I have a problem with Database Mail on SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit), Windows Server Standard 2016. If anyone who can help, I would very appreciate.

The problem is:

I moved my Data to a new server (using 1and1 server). I am using 1and1 email (ionos.co.uk) to setup Database Mail and I can send email from Database Mail to any email provider except hotmail, outlook mail. the status on sysmail_allitems is "sent"

I did setup the same way for my old server, it was working fine.

I don't know why only hotmail, Outlook mail can not receive my email.

Server: smtp.ionos.co.uk
Port: 587
I also opened all the security port for mail on firewall network and firewall server.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I sympathize.  There are lots and LOTS of reasons Microsoft might be blocking your program's e-mails.  For starters, look [here](https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/224901988-Microsoft-Outlook-com-and-Hotmail-troubleshooting-support-information), [here](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/hotmail-blacklist-removal/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/troubleshooting-mail-sent-to-office-365?view=o365-worldwide).

Comment: Hi Paulsm4,  Thank you for your suggestion. I am able to send a test email from my email, database mail on my laptop, database mail on different server (the old one) to my hotmail, outloook. However, on the new server, when i am using database mail to send an email to my hotmail, outlook, I  never receive it.

Comment: Does your sender address's domain name have [SPF (Sender Policy Framework)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records? You might need to add your new SQL Server's internet-facing IP address to the allowed sender addresses.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As of yesterday January 26th, 2021 according to Ionos/1and1's posted notice, and corroborated by my personal email sending experience having been remedied, the issue has, indeed, been resolved.

There is actually a huge issue going on as of a few days ago specifically between Ionos/1and1 & Microsoft (i.e. Hotmail, Outlook) preventing emails from being sent. Here's Ionos/1and1's status update page on the issue:
https://www.ionos-status.com/

And you can also see another thread talking about other users experiencing the same problem here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/messages-not-being-delivered/e24bf21b-01f7-4ef4-bfbf-b24bea75aad0

It's possible, that a very recent hack involving Microsoft and an Ionos-based server might just be involved with Microsoft employing mitigating methods of addressing the issue which are now leading to the current email sending limitations. You can read about the hack here: https://amp.thehackernews.com/thn/2021/01/hackers-accidentally-expose-passwords.html